# Using for-loop to iterate specific arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My ajax call returns some data but I want to eliminate it using for loop.

This for loop will get **first task name** and **last task name** for each year  let say for `2001`  it will retrieve `task1 and task4`  so on..

But there can be more tasks  and more year data not only 4  but can be 6 or 7 or 10.

The for loop will consider this too.

But the issue I am actually stuck is there is no any initial variable. Ajax returns `obj[]` arrays and each one has **taskname** and **year** .

How to assign a year as a initial variable  and start for loop?

```
  Taskname           Year

  task1               2001
  task2               2001
  task3               2001
  task4               2001
  task1-a             2002
  task2-a             2002
  task3-a             2002
  task4-a             2002
  task1-b             2003
  task2-b             2003
  task3-b             2003
  task4-b             2003
```

Comment: I have difficulties understanding what the problem is. Please try to work on a better explanation and provide a complete example, including example input, the code you have, expected output and current output.

Comment: I don't understand the question... Can you give us a jsfiddle.com with a sample of what you are doing so far?

Comment: Please post the JSON that your ajax receives, not some pseudo-description of what it might look like. Also post the code that you already have, where you struggle to get an initial variable for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should help. This considers that the records are sorted on the year

```
        var tasks = [{taskName:'task1','year':'2001'},
            {'taskName':'task2','year':'2001'},
            {'taskName':'task3','year':'2001'},
            {'taskName':'task4','year':'2001'},
            {'taskName':'task1-a','year':'2002'},
            {'taskName':'task2-a','year':'2002'},
            {'taskName':'task3-a','year':'2002'},
            {'taskName':'task4-a','year':'2002'},
            {'taskName':'task1-b','year':'2003'},
            {'taskName':'task2-b','year':'2003'},
            {'taskName':'task3-b','year':'2003'},
            {'taskName':'task4-b','year':'2003'}
        ];

        var resultArray = tasks.filter(function (item, index, array ){

            if(index === 0 || index === (array.length -1)){
                return true;
            } else if(index < (array.length -1) ){
                return (item.year !== array[index -1].year)
                ||(item.year !== array[index +1].year);
            }
        });


        alert(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
```